# Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration... Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class:

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

Please help me to resolve this error.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>
> #### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in mybatis/xml/Student.xml ### Cause:
>
> org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper
>   Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:
>   Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class.
>   Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type
>   alias 'Student'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find
>   class: Student

and here is my project folder structure 
[image]

my Student class:

```java
package mybatis.model;

public class Student {
private int id;
private String name;
private String branch;
private int percentage;
private int phone;
private String email;

    public Student(String name, String branch, int percentage, int phone, String email) {
          super();
          this.name = name;
          this.branch = branch;
          this.percentage = percentage;
          this.phone = phone;
          this.email = email;
       }
}
```

my controller class:

```java
package mybatis.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import mybatis.model.Student;

@RestController
public class mybatisController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() throws IOException {
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis/xml/SqlMapConfig.xml");
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader); 
        SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

        //Create a new student object
        Student student = new Student("Mohammad","It", 80, 984803322, "Mohammad@gmail.com" ); 

        //Insert student data      
        Integer result = session.insert("Student.insert", student);
        return result>0 ? "inserted":"fail";
    }
}
```

SqlMapConfig.xml

[image]

Student.xml

[image]

Comment: the mapper tag in SqlmapConfig.xml

<mappers>
      <mapper resource = "mybatis/xml/Student.xml"/>
   </mappers>

Comment: File SqlMapConfig.xml is missing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error with these steps

In Student.xml i replace Student parameterType with full classPath:

```
<mapper namespace="mybatis.model.Student">
```

and

```
<insert id = "insert" parameterType="mybatis.model.Student">
```

2. then do the same in mybatisController where call the insert Id of mapper:

   int result = session.insert("**mybatis.model.Student**.insert", student);